# Pypyodbc.DataError trouble with database

Tags: python, mysql, pypyodbc

I am trying to figure out why doesn't my test programme in python work.
I can access the database just fine from MySql Workbench, and I think I did everything right with the programming part, I also went to Administrative Tools and added my database to ODBC Database Sources, here is my test programme, if anyone can figure out what's wrong:

```
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect("DSN=database")


def func():
    l = []
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT foo FROM table")
    except pypyodbc.DatabaseError:
        pass
    conn.commit()
    for i in cur:
        l.append(i)
    conn.close()
    cur.close()

func()
```

The Error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/path/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    func()
  File "D:/path/test.py", line 14, in func
    for i in cur.fetchall():
  File "D:/path/test.py", line 1819, in fetchall
    row = self.fetchone()
  File "D:/path/test.py", line 1893, in fetchone
    check_success(self, ret)   
  File "D:/path/test.py", line 986, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "D:/path/test.py", line 956, in ctrl_err
    raise DataError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.0.17-MariaDB]')
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the ANSI ("(a)") version of the ODBC driver. Try using the Unicode version ("(w)") and see if that helps. Also, you don't need a `.commit()` after a SELECT statement.

Comment: Thank you it works now, it was a driver issue.

Comment: @Gord where should commit actually be used I put it there because i saw it in pypyodbc example?

Comment: .commit() is only required when SQL statements make changes to the data (e.g., INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). A simple SELECT statement only retrieves data, so no .commit() is required at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 22018 is an "invalid character" error. One common cause is trying to use the ANSI ("(a)") version of MySQL Connector/ODBC to retrieve Unicode data. In that case the solution is to use the Unicode ("(w)") version of the driver instead.

Comment: The problem was the driver, what I did was use Unicode driver, and now it works fine. Thanks for help.